# Assignment to list using pipe in R

Tags: r, variables, pipeline

Using pipe `%test%` I'd like to assign `rhs` output to `lhs` when `lhs` is list element, but as you can see new variable is created and output from `rhs` is not assigned to `lhs` (it's still `NULL`):

```
> test.list <- list(val = NULL)
> test.list$val %test% head(mtcars)
> `test.list$val`
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> test.list$val
NULL
```

MWE:

```
`%test%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  target <- substitute(lhs)
  val <- substitute(rhs)
  envir <- parent.frame()
  val.eval <- eval(val, envir = envir)
  assign(deparse(target), val.eval, envir = envir)
}

test.list <- list(val = NULL)
test.list$val %test% head(mtcars)
`test.list$val`
test.list$val
```

Comment: you're successfully assigning to the variable `'test.list$val'` , and not to the `val` element of `test.list`. The first parameter of assign is a variable name, it cannot be an expression that returns a list element.

Comment: I agree and I want to use something else than `assign()` but have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't claim it's clean :) :

```
'%test%' <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  target <- sub("^(.*?)(\\$.*)","\\1",deparse(substitute(lhs)))
  elt    <- sub("^(.*?\\$)(.*)","\\2",deparse(substitute(lhs)))
  val <- substitute(rhs)
  envir <- parent.frame()
  val.eval <- eval(val, envir = envir)
  target.eval <- eval(lhs, envir = envir)
  target.eval[[elt]] <- val.eval
  assign(target, target.eval, envir = envir)
}

test.list <- list(val = NULL)
test.list$val %test% head(mtcars)
# $val
# mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: But if name of list element is changed `test.list$a %test% head(mtcars)` it does not work :P

Comment: see edited answer, I parsed the part after the dollar sign too

Comment: I'm quite sure it's an unforgivable way to go at it, it must be possible to deparse it without regex, but that's all I have. note that `test.list[["val"]] %test% head(mtcars)` will not work